# Why Does web3py Need Provider to Initialize Contract?

Tags: web3.py

The two steps to create a contract instance in web3.py are --

```
w3 = web3.Web3(WebsocketProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/...'))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
```

Why must I supply a provider to create the contract? Initially I thought web3.py will fetch information from the network, but inspecting contract shows nothing --

```
(Pdb) contract.bytecode
```

My question in other words is: As I only need the contract skeleton for offline use and don't need to interact with the chain directly through the contract methods, is there a way to create a contract without needing to supply a provider endpoint?

Comment: I think it sets the provider in the output contract object, so that when you later call functions of that object, it can use the provider in order to execute them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Web3` instance without explicitly setting a provider, in which case `web3.providers.AutoProvider` is used. Then create the `contract` instance as normal.

```py
w3 = web3.Web3()
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
```

Comment: So it is possible, at least in web3.js; I just need to dig deeper to see if it's supported by web3.py

Comment: My answer is specifically for web3.py, the code sample I gave works for me with  v5.3.0

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't Python and JavaScript look similar... :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the contract offline, does the ABI have enough information for just the contract outline?

Also, if you are using the Truffle, the ABI is only a piece of the ContractName.json file the is created in the build folder. This JSON file has a ton of additional information, which may have what you are looking for.

Comment: ABI defines how a contract should be interfaced with, i.e., how to call it and what it returns; The frameworks, web3.py, web3.js, etc provides implementation of methods to translate between high level variables and their low level representation, which I'd rather use off-the-shelf than implement myself to, e.g., create a topics filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum nodes support different network protocols. Using a Provider you can specify which protocol you want to use (e.g. HTTP, WS, IPC).